# Need to find Average of top 3 records grouped by ID in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, average

I have a postgres table with customer ID's, dates, and integers. I need to find the average of the top 3 records for each customer ID that have dates within the last year. I can do it with a single ID using the SQL below (id is the customer ID, weekending is the date, and maxattached is the integer).

One caveat: the maximum values are per month, meaning we're only looking at the highest value in a given month to create our dataset, thus why we're extracting month from the date.

```
SELECT 
  id,
  round(avg(max),0) 
FROM 
  (
   select 
     id,
     extract(month from weekending) as month,
     extract(year from weekending) as year,
     max(maxattached) as max 
   FROM 
     myTable 
   WHERE
     weekending >= now() - interval '1 year' AND 
     id=110070 group by id,month,year 
   ORDER BY
     max desc limit 3
   ) AS t 
GROUP BY id;
```

How can I expand this query to include all ID's and a single averaged number for each one?

Here is some sample data:

```
ID     | MaxAttached | Weekending
110070 | 5           | 2011-11-10
110070 | 6           | 2011-11-17
110071 | 4           | 2011-11-10
110071 | 7           | 2011-11-17
110070 | 3           | 2011-12-01
110071 | 8           | 2011-12-01
110070 | 5           | 2012-01-01
110071 | 9           | 2012-01-01
```

So, for this sample table, I would expect to receive the following results:

```
ID     | MaxAttached

110070 | 5           
110071 | 8
```

This averages the highest value in a given month for each ID (6,3,5 for 110070 and 7,8,9 for 110071)

Note:  postgres version 8.1.15

Comment: Why you need `month` and `year` in subquery? And are you sure, you query works as you achieve?

Comment: I need month & year to ensure that I am only taking one value per calendar month. If I didn't have those values, I might end up with multiple of my highest values in a single month, which for business purposes I want to avoid.

Comment: Correct your question. ` I need to find the average of the top 3 records for each customer ID that have dates within the last year.` Where are you see about one value per month?

Comment: To reconfirm, so do you want to get 3 customers who have max average per their last year records?

Comment: Could you put some sample data and the result you're after up.  As I understand it, you're wanting for each customer(based on ID), the average of their three highest records (maxattached), as long as those orders are in different months(weekending)

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear. I need to find the top three records for each customer ID that have dates within the last year and there cannot be multiple records that have the same year and month for a particular ID.

Comment: Added sample data above.

Comment: ***8.1***? really? You should upgrade **now**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - get the `max(maxattached)` for every customer and month:

```
SELECT id,
       max(maxattached) as max_att         
FROM myTable 
WHERE weekending >= now() - interval '1 year' 
GROUP BY id, date_trunc('month',weekending);
```

Next - for every customer rank all his values:

```
SELECT id,
       max_att,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY max_att DESC) as max_att_rank
FROM <previous select here>;
```

Next - get the top 3 for every customer:

```
SELECT id,
       max_att
FROM <previous select here>
WHERE max_att_rank <= 3;
```

Next - get the `avg` of the values for every customer:

```
SELECT id,
       avg(max_att) as avg_att
FROM <previous select here>
GROUP BY id;
```

Next - just put all the queries together and rewrite/simplify them for your case.

UPDATE: Here is an SQLFiddle with your test data and the queries: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a81e6/4).

UPDATE2: Here is the query, that will work on 8.1 :

```
SELECT customer_id,
       (SELECT round(avg(max_att),0)
        FROM (SELECT max(maxattached) as max_att         
              FROM table1
              WHERE weekending >= now() - interval '2 year' 
                AND id = ct.customer_id
              GROUP BY date_trunc('month',weekending)
              ORDER BY max_att DESC
              LIMIT 3) sub 
        ) as avg_att
FROM customer_table ct;
```

The idea - to take your initial query and run it for every customer (`customer_table` - table with all unique `id` for customers).

Here is SQLFiddle with this query: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/a36a6/4).

Only tested on version 8.3 (8.1 is too old to be on SQLFiddle).

Comment: *sigh* this looks great. Unfortunately, I am running postgres 8.1.15, which apparently does not support OVER (PARTITION BY) functions.

Comment: @user882134 8.1.15 ? You definitely need to read [this](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: @user882134 I will try to write the query for your system, but it can be painfully slow on large data sets.

Comment: This is perfect! I've made one small tweak to sort max_att DESC instead of ASC...I think you just got lucky with your dataset, but this sorts by the largest values instead of the smallest in each month.

Answer (score 0):

**8.3 version**

8.3 is the oldest version I've got access to, so I can't guarantee it'll work in 8.1

I'm using a temporary table to work out the best three records.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_highest_per_month as
   select 
     id,
     extract(month from weekending) as month,
     extract(year from weekending) as year,
     max(maxattached) as max_in_month,
     0 as priority
   FROM 
     myTable 
   WHERE
     weekending >= now() - interval '1 year' 
   group by id,month,year;

UPDATE temp_highest_per_month t
SET priority = 
 (select count(*) from temp_highest_per_month t2
  where t2.id = t.id and 
   (t.max_in_month < t2.max_in_month or
     (t.max_in_month= t2.max_in_month and
      t.year * 12 + t.month > t2.year * 12 + t.month)));

select id,round(avg(max_in_month),0)
from temp_highest_per_month
where priority <= 3
group by id;
```

The year & month are included in the working out the priority so that if two months have the same maximum, they'll still be included in the numbering correctly.

**9.1 version**

Similar to Igor's answer, but I used the With clause to split the steps.

```
with highest_per_month as
  ( select 
     id,
     extract(month from weekending) as month,
     extract(year from weekending) as year,
     max(maxattached) as max_in_month
   FROM 
     myTable 
   WHERE
     weekending >= now() - interval '1 year' 
   group by id,month,year),
  prioritised as
  ( select id, month, year, max_in_month,
    row_number() over (partition by id, month, year
                       order by max_in_month desc)
    as priority
    from highest_per_month
   )
select id, round(avg(max_in_month),0)
from prioritised
where priority <= 3
group by id;
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment on Igor's answer, this will break for the same reason.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does, but it does seem like with some gruesome nested queries it can be converted.

Comment: @Gary The 8.3 query can be done in one `SELECT`. The first `SELECT` [here](http://www.depesz.com/2012/10/05/getting-top-n-rows-per-group/) shows how.